# Persisting Data between View States AngularJs with smart Table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, smart-table

I am currently using [Smart Table](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/),

so far everything is working like a charm. It is the workflow my web app requires that is causing my issue.

My application has two states

1. New Order
2. Current Order

Doesn't seem hard but this is where it starts to get tricky.
I can filter the data in the New Order and select what i want and have it fire to the API with no problem.

Its State 2 where i get the error of returning with existing data in the grid and it now being "isSelected". As well they are able to add more items to the selected items and even remove these old items.

I have tried accessing this with a $watcher and with no luck but it does work for a simple part of what i needed.

```
 $scope.$watch('ctrl.selectedItem', function (newVal) {
        _.filter(newVal, function (item) {
            //add totals for the blocks
            if (item.isSelected) {
                Order.totals.planted = workOrder.totals.planted + item.Planted;
                Order.totals.treatable = Order.totals.treatable + item.Treatable;
                Order.totals.rowarea = Order.totals.rowarea + item.RowArea;
                Order.totals.gross = Order.totals.gross + item.Gross;
            } else {

            }
        });
    }, true);
```

This part works great and lets me see when data has been updated in the "selectedItem" array and add the totals up of all the new items.

I would like to do something similar but select current items and allow people to add new items to the selected items. All of this of course being handled at the DOM level.

What would be the best way to do this with Smart Table, i have went through a lot of different options and everything that Smart Table offers doesn't seem to provide a solution to this issue and i want to use as much as i can from this module.

any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using a factory to persist your data?

Comment: @Ohjay44 I have a factory that is working to call all of my API calls and that's it.

Comment: You can use that same factory to persist data between views / state, I will provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated you can use a service to share data across states, views, controllers, other services, and factories. See this plunker example https://plnkr.co/edit/YKlIx1t32QopPCfpiF7n?p=preview and this script. If you have multiple angular modules in your project you can even set your service up as a standalone module itself and inject it into other modules. For simplicity this example is contained within one module and HTML page:

```
angular.module('orderExample', [])
        .factory('orderTrackingService', orderTrackingService)
        .controller('NewOrderController', NewOrderController)
        .controller('CurrentOrderController', CurrentOrderController);


    /* Service */
    function orderTrackingService() {
        var order = {
            selectedItems: [],
            totals: {
                planted: 0,
                treatable: 0,
                rowarea: 0,
                gross: 0
            }
        };

        return  {
            getOrder: getOrder,
        };

        function getOrder() {
            return order;
        }
    }

    /* State 1 Controller */
    NewOrderController.$inject = ['orderTrackingService'];

    function NewOrderController(orderTrackingService) {
        this.order = orderTrackingService.getOrder();
        this.selectItem = selectItem;
        this.newItem = {};
        /* call this from View on select */
        function selectItem(item) {

            this.order.selectedItems.push(item);
            this.order.totals.planted += item.planted;
            this.order.totals.treatable += item.treatable;
            this.order.totals.rowarea += item.rowarea;
            this.order.totals.gross += item.gross;
            this.newItem = {};
        }

    }


    /* State 2 Controller */
    NewOrderController.$inject = ['orderTrackingService'];

    function CurrentOrderController(orderTrackingService) {

        /* Gets reference to object from service. All changes to object properties will reflect here */
        this.order = orderTrackingService.getOrder();
    }
```